# Mutable self while reading from owner object

Tags: rust

I have one object that owns another. The owned object has a mutating method that depends on non-mutating methods of its owner. The architecture (simplified as much as possible) looks like this:

```
struct World {
    animals: Vec<Animal>,
}

impl World {
    fn feed_all(&mut self) {
        for i in 0..self.animals.len() {
            self.animals[i].feed(self);
        }
    }
}

struct Animal {
    food: f32,
}

impl Animal {
    fn inc_food(&mut self) {
        self.food += 1.0;
    }

    fn feed(&mut self, world: &World) {
        // Imagine this is a much more complex calculation, involving many
        // queries to world.animals, several loops, and a bunch of if
        // statements. In other words, something so complex it can't just
        // be moved outside feed() and pass its result in as a pre-computed value.
        for other_animal in world.animals.iter() {
            self.food += 10.0 / (other_animal.food + self.food);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut world = World {
        animals: Vec::with_capacity(1),
    };

    world.animals.push(Animal { food: 0.0 });

    world.feed_all();
}
```

The above does not compile. The compiler says:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because `self.animals` is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:8:34
  |
8 |             self.animals[i].feed(self);
  |             ------------         ^^^^- mutable borrow ends here
  |             |                    |
  |             |                    immutable borrow occurs here
  |             mutable borrow occurs here
```

I understand why that error occurs, but what is the idiomatic Rust way to do this?

Just to be clear, the example code is not real. It's meant to present the core problem as simply as possible. The real application I'm writing is much more complex and has nothing to do with animals and feeding.

Assume it is not practical to pre-compute the food value before the call to `feed()`. In the real app, the method that's analogous to `feed()` makes many calls to the `World` object and does a lot of complex logic with the results.

Comment: It's very difficult to give good answers when the question changes with each new answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In summary: Rust is *doing the right thing* by refusing to compile what I wrote. There's no way to know at compile time that I won't invalidate the data I'm using. If I get a mutable pointer to one animal, the compiler can't know that my read-only access to the vector isn't invalidated by my mutations to that particular animal.

Because this can't be determined at compile time, we need some kind of runtime check, or we need to use unsafe operations to bypass the safety checks altogether.

`RefCell` is the way to go if we want safety at the cost of runtime checks. `UnsafeCell` is at least one option to solve this without the overhead, at the cost of safety of course.

I've concluded that `RefCell` is preferable in most cases. The overhead should be minimal. That's especially true if we're doing anything even moderately complex with the values once we obtain them: The cost of the useful operations will dwarf the cost of `RefCell`'s checks. While `UnsafeCell` might be a little faster, it invites us to make mistakes.

Below is an example program solving this class of problem with `RefCell`. Instead of animals and feeding, I chose players, walls, and collision detection. Different scenery, same idea. This solution is generalizable to a lot of very common problems in game programming. For example:

- A map composed of 2D tiles, where the render state of each tile depends on its neighbors. E.g. grass next to water needs to render a coast texture. The render state of a given tile updates when that tile or any of its neighbors changes.
- An AI declares war against the player if any of the AI's allies are at war with the player.
- A chunk of terrain is calculating its vertex normals, and it needs to know the vertex positions of the neighboring chunks.

Anyway, here's my example code:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Vector2 {x: f32, y: f32}

impl Vector2 {
    fn add(&self, other: &Vector2) -> Vector2 {
        Vector2 {x: self.x + other.x, y: self.y + other.y}
    }
}

struct World {
    players: Vec<RefCell<Player>>,
    walls: Vec<Wall>
}

struct Wall;

impl Wall {
    fn intersects_line_segment(&self, start: &Vector2, stop: &Vector2) -> bool {
        // Pretend this actually does a computation.
        false
    }
}

struct Player {position: Vector2, velocity: Vector2}

impl Player {
    fn collides_with_anything(&self, world: &World, start: &Vector2, stop: &Vector2) -> bool {
        for wall in world.walls.iter() {
            if wall.intersects_line_segment(start, stop) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for cell in world.players.iter() {
            match cell.try_borrow_mut() {
                Some(player) => {
                  if player.intersects_line_segment(start, stop) {
                      return true;
                  }
                },
                // We don't want to collision detect against this player. Nor can we,
                // because we've already mutably borrowed this player. So its RefCell
                // will return None.
                None => {}
            }
        }

        false
    }

    fn intersects_line_segment(&self, start: &Vector2, stop: &Vector2) -> bool {
        // Pretend this actually does a computation.
        false
    }

    fn update_position(&mut self, world: &World) {
        let new_position = self.position.add(&self.velocity);
        if !Player::collides_with_anything(self, world, &self.position, &new_position) {
            self.position = new_position;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let world = World {
        players: vec!(
            RefCell::new(
              Player {
                  position: Vector2 { x: 0.0, y: 0.0},
                  velocity: Vector2 { x: 1.0, y: 1.0}
              }
            ),
            RefCell::new(
              Player {
                  position: Vector2 { x: 1.1, y: 1.0},
                  velocity: Vector2 { x: 0.0, y: 0.0}
              }
            )
        ),

        walls: vec!(Wall, Wall)
    };

    for cell in world.players.iter() {
        let player = &mut cell.borrow_mut();
        player.update_position(&world);
    }
}
```

The above could be altered to use `UnsafeCell` with very few changes. But again,I think `RefCell` is preferable in this case and in most others.

Thanks to @DK for putting me on the right track to this solution.

Comment: If you think that games provide an accurate metaphor for your need, perhaps you should check out [rust-gamedev](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust_gamedev/) or the [IRC channel](http://chat.mibbit.com/?server=irc.mozilla.org&channel=%23rust-gamedev) of the same.

Comment: How so? Do you mean you don't think the pattern I've identified above is common in games? If so, I'm open to criticism of the architecture I've chosen. Just bear in mind that certain choices, such as in-place updating, are dictated by performance concerns rather than my own personal tastes.

Comment: Oh, I can't agree or disagree, I don't have enough experience in the domain to make that call. I'm just trying to point out some more resources, specifically people doing games in Rust, that might be able to help translate your pattern to how it could apply in Rust.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks! /r/rust-gamedev is great. It just so happens that today, a project popped up on that sub which had this exact type of problem. Indeed, the author of that project went with `RefCell`. (And also `Rc`, in some cases.)

Answer (score 3):

You'd want to compute the argument *first* in a form that doesn't alias `self`, then pass that in.  As it stands, it seems a little strange that an animal decides how much food it's going to eat by looking at every other animal... regardless, you could add a method `Animal::decide_feed_amount(&self, world: &World) -> f32`.  You can call that safely (`&self` and `&World` are both immutable, so that's OK), store the result in a variable, then pass that to `Animal::feed`.

**Edit to address your Edit**: well, you're kinda screwed, then.  Rust's borrow checker is not sophisticated enough to prove that the mutations you make to the `Animal` cannot possibly interfere with any possible immutable access to the containing `World`.  Some things you can try:

- Do a functional-style update.  Make a copy of the `Animal` you want to update so that it has its own lifetime, update it, then overwrite the original.  If you duplicate the whole array up front, this gives you what is *effectively* an atomic update of the whole array.

  As someone who worked on a simulator for like half a decade, I *wish* I'd done something like that instead of mutating updates.  *sigh*
- Change to `Vec<Option<Animal>>` which will allow you to move (not copy) an `Animal` out of the array, mutate it, then put it back (see `std::mem::replace`).  Downside is that now everything has to check to see if there's an animal in each position of the array.
- Put the `Animal`s inside `Cell`s or `RefCell`s, which will allow you to mutate them from immutable references.  It does this by performing dynamic borrow checking which is infinitely slower (no checks vs. some checks), but is still "safe".
- Absolute last resort: `unsafe`.  But really, if you do that, you're throwing all your memory safety guarantees out the window, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Unfortunately, computing the value first isn't possible. I'll edit my post to state that clearly.

Comment: Can you talk more about using unsafe? I didn't realize it could be used to bypass the borrow checker?

Comment: Not in SO comments.  I could tell you just about enough to let you completely hose your program, but I feel that's a bad idea.  If you're not 100% certain on how memory safety is enforced in Rust, you probably shouldn't be touching `unsafe`.

Comment: Ok, but Rust is billed as a "systems programming language." This seems like a pretty common need in systems programming. I find it hard to believe Rust can't do it without a bunch of unnecessary runtime safety checks.

Comment: All the compiler knows is that you've got two references pointing into the same region, and one of them is mutable.  Humans are *notoriously* bad at getting this stuff right, and it can't prove that you aren't going to use the mutable one to invalidate the immutable one, so it stops you.  `unsafe` is how you override the compiler, but I don't want to seriously suggest that without going into detail on what invariants you need to then manually assert, and this isn't the place for that.  If you don't know what using `unsafe` entails, you shouldn't be using it.  Runtime checks = price of safety.

Comment: Fair point. I agree. Do you know where I can read more about `unsafe`'s use in overriding the borrow checker? I've been Googling, but I haven't found a single reference on this topic. Or is it an undocumented feature?

Comment: The only one I can really find is in the [Unsafe section of the Rust Book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/unsafe.html#references).