# Having trouble with proper design pattern

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a simple game engine, but the normal patterns I would use to do this don't work here due to the strict borrowing rules.

There is a `World` struct which owns a collection of `Object` trait objects. We can think of these as moving physical objects in the game engine. `World` is responsible for calling `update` and `draw` on each of these during each game tick.

The `World` struct also owns a collection of `Event` trait objects. Each of these events encapsulates an arbitrary piece of code that modifies the `objects` during the game ticks.

Ideally, the `Event` trait object has a single method `do_event` that takes no arguments that can be called by `World` during each game tick. The problem is that a particular `Event` needs to have mutable references to the objects that it modifies but these objects are owned by `World`. We could have `World` pass mutable references to the necessary objects when it calls `do_event` for each event, but how does it know which objects to pass to each event object?

If this were C++ or Python, when constructing a particular `Event`, I would pass the target of the event to the constructor where it would be saved and then used during `do_event`. Obviously, this doesn't work in Rust because the targets are all owned by `World` so we cannot store mutable references elsewhere.

I could add some ID system and a lookup table so `World` knows which objects to pass to which `Event`s but this is messy and costly. I suspect my entire way of approaching this class of problem needs to change, however, I am stumped.

A sketch of my code:

```
trait Object {
    fn update(&mut self);
    fn draw(&self);
}

trait Event {
    fn do_event(&mut self);
}

struct World {
    objects: Vec<Box<dyn Object + 'a>>,
    events: Vec<Box<dyn Event + 'a>>,
}

impl World {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        for obj in self.objects.iter_mut() {
            obj.update();
        }
        for evt in self.events.iter_mut() {
            evt.do_event();
        }
    }
    fn draw(&mut self) { /*...*/ }
}

struct SomeEvent<'a, T: Object> {
    target: &'a mut T,
}

impl<'a, T: Object> Event for SomeEvent<'a, T> {
    fn update(&self) {
        self.target.do_shrink(); // need mutable reference here
    }
}
```

I know that `RefCell` enables multiple objects to obtain mutable references. Perhaps that is the direction I should go. However, based on [what I learned from the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html), I got the sense that `RefCell`s break some of Rust's main ideas by introducing unsafe code and circular references. I guess I was just wondering if there was some other obvious design pattern that adhered more to the idiomatic way of doing things.

Comment: *I could add some ID system and a lookup table* — congratulations, you've discovered [entity component systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system#Game_example), not a hack.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Need holistic explanation about Rust's cell and reference counted types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45674479/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: See also [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423); [Mutable self while reading from owner object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28385339/155423); [Passing mutable self reference to method of owned object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30681468/155423); [Mutable reference to container object within iterator loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40196586/155423).

Comment: And now for something completely different: A useful answer. https://github.com/amethyst/specs

Comment: *`RefCell`s break some of Rust's main ideas by introducing unsafe code* — `RefCell` introduces the same amount of unsafe code as `Vec` does — are you ok with using `Vec` or `String`? *and circular references* — `RefCell` does not allow for circular references; perhaps you are thinking of `Rc`?

Comment: Because this question in its current form appears off-topic (asking for "the right design pattern" is opinion-based, at best), you may wish to look at other resources. More open-ended questions and discussions are welcome on [the Rust users forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/), [the Rust subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/), [the Rust Discord server](https://www.rust-lang.org/community), or [the Stack Overflow Rust chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust).

Comment: I'm torn. It does read as opinion-based but I do feel that architecture questions are on-topic, and this one identifies a specific problem with enough detail that one could make a suggestion. Perhaps it could be rephrased to focus on "How do I do this?" rather than "How do I do this *in the best way*?" (obviously, when asking a question you always want the best answer).

Comment: Be sure to watch [kyren's RustConf 2018 talk on using Rust for game dev](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKLntZcp27M); it deals with a lot of the architectural decisions you are likely facing.

Comment: Yes, this is on a pretty fine line, and some editing might clearly push it one way or the other.

Comment: The original version of the question didn't mention `RefCell`, but when I [pointed it out to the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59617276/having-trouble-with-proper-design-pattern#comment105398052_59617276) they rejected it as a possible answer. It would be good for the OP to preemptively [edit] to put **all** the arbitrary restrictions they have so that any answerer doesn't waste anyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the question comments and watching [kyren's RustConf 2018 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKLntZcp27M) (thanks [trentcl](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/166944/trentcl)), I've realized the OO approach to my game engine is fundamentally incompatible with Rust (or at least quite difficult).

After working on this for a day or so, I would highly recommend watching the posted video and then using the [specs](https://docs.rs/specs/0.15.1/specs/) library (an implementation of the ECS system mentioned by user2722968).

Hope this helps someone else in the future.